# Loop not halting at break?

Tags: java

I wrote a name checker that uses a for loop to check if each individual character in the string is a letter, and I wrote an if statement within the for loop stating that if the if statement conditions are met, print "Your name is valid!" and break. But if the conditions are not met, rerun the loop.

```
public static void nameValid() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your name");
    String name = in.nextLine();
    int q = name.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(name.charAt(i)) && q >= 2) {
            System.out.println("Your name is valid!");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your name is invalid! Please enter a valid name!");
            nameValid();
        }
    }
}
```

If I enter a valid string the first time around, everything is fine, and it moves on to the second method. If I enter an invalid String, it gives me the expected error message and reruns the loop. But then when I enter a valid string after that, it continuously runs the loop. The output I get is this:

```
Enter your name
123
Your name is invalid! Please enter a valid name!
Enter your name
fred
Your name is valid!
Your name is invalid! Please enter a valid name!
Enter your name
```

Comment: Are you sure the output belongs to the code you have provided here. I don't think so.

Comment: Say you fall into the `else` clause. Now you call yourself recursively. When that call eventually returns, you continue the loop. Is this what you want? Why are you using recursion for this anyway?

Comment: @DeanMeehan are you really so quick to attribute a very simple logical error to a compiler bug?

Answer (score 4):

It's not re-running the loop...  it's entering a recursive function call.

(Use a debugger next time please.)

Answer (score 1):

In your `else` block, you're calling the `nameValid` function recursively within a loop. Thus, when you finally do enter a valid name and hit the `break` line, the loop that originally called the function continues.